# How do I stop, abort or cancel ApplyBindings during processing?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I know there is no callback mechanism i can hook into... but can I cancel or abort an `applyBindings` call?

This is important if for example I have asynchronous calls happening to collect component templates etc.

Comment: I almost added another close vote ("Needs a repro"), but then I realized the literal question you ask is minimal but valid. - More than likely (as indicated by you mentioning you wanted to try and create a jsfiddle) you have an XY-problem. I suggest asking a seperate question about X with a repro. (If you end up editing *this* question so it is no longer Y, but X: please ping me in a comment, because that would invalidate my answer.)

Comment: I think you might be right - perhaps this edit is suitable?

Comment: I have posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121483/knockout-component-fails-if-element-removed-before-template-returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

There is no feature in KO to abort or cancel an in-progress `applyBindings` call.